# How to use TCP Client in Android without Sockets?

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I have a TCP server in C# and also a TCP Client in C#, now I need a TCP Client in Android too.

All the examples i found are related to sockets, but I'm using a simple TCP Client so they don't work.

Right now my C# TCP Client is like that:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1200);
        NetworkStream n = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert name");
        string name= Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] message = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(name);
        n.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
```

Is there a corresponding of this function in Android?

This is the actual android client i'm trying and that doesn't work

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 1200);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
```

Comment: There is a socket in `TcpClient`. So, use sockets in Android

Comment: I tried and the connection doesn't work. So I guess you can't send socket if your server is not set to work as socket but just as a tcpclient

Comment: There is NO difference between TcpClient and socket. It didn't work for another reason.

Comment: i just edited the post adding the client i'm trying and that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(127.0.0.1);
```

contains a syntax error. It should be:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
```

Second, the address "127.0.0.1" refers to the "same machine" that executes the client. In the case of your C# program, the server runs on the same machine as the client, so it worked. But in the case of Android, there in no server that runs on the "same machine", which is your Android phone (event if it is emulated, 127.0.0.1 refers to the emulated Android device, not the PC that it works on). You must specify a "good" address to the Android device that refers to the machine on which the server executes.

So, the problem is not in using sockets.

Comment: about 12.0.0.1, it was just a mistake when i copied the code here, in the real code everything is fine. now i try what you said about the emulator

Comment: ok now the connection works, but when i send a message, it says 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
the problem is when i try to parse the string in an integer, even if the message is just a number. this problem isn't present in the c# client version. so i still think it could be related to sockets

Comment: Again, it is not related to sockets. Print the message on the console in the server side to see what it receives. Also, add `out.flush();` after `out.println(str);`

Comment: i made a test, i just print the string i get from the client, and the console prints: ??????????
so there must be a problem because the server doesn't get the real message

Comment: This is an encoding problem. Try `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream();` And show us the server

Comment: it gets the same error. i decided to open a new question for this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393788/tcp-server-gets-instead-of-the-real-message
feel free to answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect to your server using this line, also try to disable your firewall if your server is running on your PC.

```
Socket server= new Socket("192.168.1.1", 4444); // Enter your PC/Server IP address in place of 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: the connection works but the server can't understand the message. if i send "hello" it gets: "???????????"