# TCP Server gets ???????? instead of the real message

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

The server is written in c# and works correctly with a client I made in c#, now i'm trying to make an android client but the server doesn't get the real message, it gets just a lot of question marks.

Here is the server

```
TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1200);
TcpClient client;
listen.Start();
client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
int data = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

this is the Android client

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
String str = et.getText().toString()
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
out.println(str);
```

For example if I send the message "Hello", the server prints "???????????" and it happens the same for any message I send, even just 1 letter

I also tried with different methods like this one but the result is the same:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(str);
```

Comment: Looks like an encoding trouble. Check what encoding is set on server

Comment: What do you mean Nikita? I tried to change the Android client in PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
but I still get the same error

Comment: `String str = et.getText().toString()`. Better use a predefined string. And tell us how many bytes are sent and how many bytes received.

Comment: I tried String str = "hello"; but it stil gets only ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
string message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
```

into:

```
string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, data);
```

Try also `UTF16`. I think java uses this encoding now.

Comment: yeah, in this way it works. is there a way to make android sends the message in unicode instead of utf8?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606523/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-unicode-in-java